# BrowserSession.LoginComplete event not working even after successful login on Facebook through SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

When I log in to Facebook through the Browsersession.Login() it works fine, but
BrowserSession.LoginComplete event isn't working during this Period.

Can anybody suggest why this thing is happening in my project?

Comment: Please provide more details, preferably including some code as an example

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your connect URL in your Facebook application.
   If you are working on localhost then it should be:  http://localhost:[port#]
2. Check your fblogin.js file where your xd_receiver.htm path should be correct 
   (check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Facebook.init/)

Also check:

1. Check that you are using right API Key for browser session
2. In fblogin.js silverlightPluginId is correct.
   Example below:
   SLHostPage:

   ```
   <div id="silverlightControlHost">
       <object id="_sl_facebookapp" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
           width="100%" height="100%">
           <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightFacebookApp.xap" />
           <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
           <param name="background" value="white" />
           <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
           <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
           <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40624.0" style="text-decoration: none">
               <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                   style="border-style: none" />
           </a>
       </object>
       <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
           border: 0px"></iframe>
   </div>
   ```

   fblogin.js:
   // Verify this variable matches the Silverlight plugin ID
   var silverlightPluginId = '_sl_facebookapp';
3. Check your SL app that you implemented the event handler

_browserSession.LoginCompleted += browserSession_LoginCompleted;

```
    private void browserSession_LoginCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _facebookAPI = new Api(_browserSession);
    }
```

See : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/d14b0ac5-4539-4cae-ba9e-4020e488d458